# Как переписать конфиг nginx на apache для статики?

Tags: nginx, apache2

Есть такая часть nginx конфига

```
location  ~ ^/backend/((img/|css/|fonts/|js/).*)$ {

     alias /var/www/project/application/backend/static/$1;

     access_log off;

     expires max;

  }
```

Как переписать это под apache?

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос не имеет особого практического смысла.

Когда применяются подобные конструкции в nginx -- это означает, что есть два веб-сервера, которые находятся друг за другом: nginx в качестве фронтенда (как правило, раздаёт статику) и httpd в качестве бекенда (отдаёт в связке с PHP динамический контент).

В случае, когда вы хотите убрать nginx и оставить только один апач -- смысл в директиве проксирования на бекенд пропадает. Чисто гипотетически есть очень редкие конфигурации с mod_proxy (когда за апачем стоит другой веб-сервер), но практического смысла такое нет.

Поэтому переписывать имеет смысл только директивы access_log off и expires max для статики.

Первая вообще в терминах apache не имеет смысла: в апаче можно отключить error_log, но полностью отключить access_log (по крайней мере, из коробки штатными средствами невозможно.

Для expire_max (сто лет не крутил на апаче могу ошибаться) есть отдельный mod_expires.

В любом случае, повторю ещё раз: уходя от связки двух веб-серверов к одному эти директивы проброса с одного веб-сервера на другой вырождаются.

Кроме того, если вы хотите уйти от nginx+apache, то более современным вариантом является уход в "чистый" nginx (а в качестве бекенда для PHP использовать php-fpm, а не apache+PHP).